# App for recording waypoints and photos for GIS on android

Tags: android, field-mapping, photos

I'm looking to collect photos and notes during a field trip to add to (just for comparison) a landcover raster dataset I'm working with.

Ideally I want to visit certain field sites, take photos with my android phone, and afterwards be able to locate each photo on my map/GIS when I'm back home.

The standard location saving feature of the android camera isn't reliable enough.

I tried MapIt, which has a lot of features I don't need, but is costly. MapPad doesn't seem to permit exports into suitable formats.

Comment: Try Geopaparazzi http://geopaparazzi.github.io/geopaparazzi/

Answer (score 1):

You can try [NextGIS Mobile](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-mobile/). This application supports tracks recording, attaching photo and attributes to a new feature and much more. See instructions here:

- http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngmobile/source/tracks.html#recording-a-track
- http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngmobile/source/editing.html#editing-attributes

Answer (score 0):

SW Maps is a simple, free android app with which you can place points on a map (using satellite images from Google, and your GPS), with custom fields including photos associated with them.  You can then export the data as shapefiles and email them to yourself, though that doesn't include the photos which is annoying.  It's easy enough to find the photos in your phone's gallery, and the shapefile data does reference the file-names of the photos.  The photos themselves don't have GPS data in them, which is a bit annoying also.

So, it's not perfect, but it'll probably do, and you'll be up and running very quickly.